# Duplicates and incomplete responses Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I'm using facebook Graph API explorer( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ) and I am pretty sure something is not going well there. I am using the query `" search?q=Bucharest&type=event&since=1486478766&until=1487342766 "` . The first page returns events as expected. But when I am trying to access "next" pages(pagination) I am getting the same results, with the same ID, description etc. I also noticed that there are more public events with "Bucharest" in metadata in this period but Graph API isn't returning them. Is there a Graph API bug or it's me doing something wrong ?

Comment: As the documentation explains, this searches in the event name only - not in any other meta data.

Comment: For the query above it also returns events with the query not included in the event name

Comment: Well then maybe it searches _some_ other fields too (like f.e. the name of the page/place). But you can not expect it to search inside the complete “meta data” (whatever that actually is supposed to encompass). Graph API search functionality is very rudimentary.

Comment: So, graph API isn't a good idea for a full public events fetch? Any alternatives?

Comment: No, not really.